# Magento 2.4.5-p1 product list shows only maximum of 10 products

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.4.5

I have an issue with a Magento shop after upgrading from 2.4.0 to 2.4.5-p1, when I open the product list on any of the categories it won't show more than 10 items. The pagination at the bottom seems to reflect the correct amount of items (ie. when there are 36 items, it shows 4 pages),  but when I go to page 2 it just shows the same 10 items as on page 1.

Filtering works as expected, when I set a filter that filters out 3 items from those 10 items, the page will still only show 10 items, but now with 3 additional items to replace the 3 filtered out items. So it looks like the system is working correctly but capping it at 10 items to show.

I changed the theme from the normally used theme (Rokanthemes BS kubix) to the build in Luma theme to rule out the theme as the source of the issue, in Luma the issue also exist.
I already reindex everything a couple of time, have done setup:di:compile multiple times and have done the setup:static-content-deploy.
I checked/updated Mysql, elasticsearch, php8.1, and the installed php8.1 modules. The issue was already present on php7.4, switching to 8.1 did not help.

System.log does not show errors or criticals (there are some info and warnings about broken references when using the normal theme, that was one the reasons to check with Luma too).

The shop contains two stores, and I have a test and a production environment. strange thing is that on the production environment the issue exists in both stores, but in the test environment the issue exist only in 1 of the two stores, the second one is working mostly as expected, it has 1 thing, at the line 'Showing 1-x out of y results', y shows the amount of items on that page, not the total amount of items within the filter, but I suspect that's a different issue.
I checked all the settings between the four stores (two on the test and two on the production) but can't find any setting that is different for the correctly functioning store.
I applied the patch for SearchResultApplier.php

Anyone has an idea where this issue might come from, or what things I can look into to find the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue ended up being caused by a plugin that is used that didn't update itself automaticaly to latest version. The plugin was Restrict by Customer Group from FME extensions and altough seems unrelated to the issue did cause the problems. After manually updating the plugin to the latest (2.4.5 compatible) version, the issue is resolved.